# Hash functions violating some pre image properties

Tags: hash, cryptography, hash-collision

Suppose **H(xy) = H(x) * H(y)** .  Clearly preimage properties are violated. How can we find x, y such that **H(x) = H(y) mod (2^k)**

Comment: x=y would be an obvious solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question directly related to programming.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Not all *tags* are directly related to programming. The justification of such tags, and such questions, is that these topics are manifestly *indirectly* related to programming. Computer programming doesn't have sharp boundaries.

Comment: I know, but this is sort of a math thing.

Comment: If you define a hash function as a function which maps integers of arbitrary size to integers of a fixed size then the only hash functions that can satisfy your condition are hash functions whose values are always either 0 and 1, in which case your problem is trivially easy to solve. Perhaps you meant something like `H(ab) = H(a)H(b) mod 2^k` where the hash size is k-bits?

Comment: @JohnColeman - ya you are right. I should have written mod 2^k . If you can tell me the answers I would be really obliged to you.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes - if u know then plzz tell me or email me. I am eager to know this.

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried? Also -- do you know of any hash functions which this property (other than `H(x) = x (mod 2^k)`)?

Comment: @JohnColeman - Actually the thing is the above problem was given with a hint related to use of Euler totient function ; presently I don't know the hash function, but i am sure you can surely use the above hint.

Comment: Please see crypto.stackexchange.com for these kinds of questions. Some more background would likely be helpful to separate it from a basic homework question, however.

Comment: Euler's theorem is probably what the hint is alluding to.

Comment: @JohnColeman : ya, that's what the hint was given. Any proceedings . update ?? I tried a lot using a fact about Euler totient function that x^(phi(2^k)) = 1 mod 2^k . But was unable to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2^k` is a very special modulus. You can prove the following strengthened version of Euler's theorem:

Suppose that `x` is any postive integer. Then `x^phi(2^k) (mod 2^k)` is equal to either 0 or 1, with 1 if and only if `x` is odd.

Proof:

If `x` is odd, then `gcd(x,2^k) = 1`, hence `x^phi(2^k) (mod 2^k) = 1` by Euler's theorem.

Suppose that `x` is even. The result is trivially true if `x = 0`, so suppose that `x > 0`. Write `x = (2^s)*y` where `y` is odd and `s > 0`. Note that

phi(2^k)` = 2^(k-1)

But then,

```
x^phi(2^k) = (2^s*y)^phi(2^k)
           = (2^s)^phi(2^k) * y^phi(2^k)
           = 2^(s*phi(2^k)) * y^phi(2^k)
           = 2^(s*2^(k-1)) * y^phi(2^k)
           = 0 * y^phi(2^k) = 0 (mod 2^k)
```

the last line follows from the fact that `s*2^(k-1) >= k` hence `2^(s*2^(k-1))` is a multiple of `2^k`.

Note that if `x` is even then you actually have `x^k = 0 (mod 2^k)`, so raising `x` to the power `phi(2^k)` is overkill for any but the smallest `k`.

Given this lemma, it is now trivial to see that there exists distinct `x`,`y` with either `H(x) = H(y) = 0` or `H(x) = H(y) = 1`. Since it seems to be homework, I'll leave the details to you.